# asp.net mvc web deployment to hosting space (cant find “Publishing” Tab in my Website Panel )

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-deployment, windows-hosting

I can able to deploy my mvc website through FTP but i cant able to use "Web deployment" method. Following youtube video suggest that i have to enable "Web Deploy" in Publishing tab 
[How to Use Web Deploy With Website Panel Windows 2012 Server](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76Serxlamag)  
it has a Publishing tab

i cant see “Management” Tab. in my site ...... :( it has only HomeFolder, MIME Type, Virtual Dir, Extention, Custom Error, Header(Total 6 tab only).
[image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBUtk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think hosting service provider just in active your option for `Management` tab. You are not authorized to have access to this part of online publicity.Please contact you hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to allow option 'Remote Web Management' in your hosting plan only then you will be able to view 'Web publishing' under website.

Can you provide more details like do you have shared hosting or a VPS.
If you have shared hosting then you will need to contact your Hosting provider and If you have a VPS then you will need to follow below steps.

1. Login into Website Panel
2. Go to the plan of your domain for which you want to publish
3. You need to enable option 'Remote Web Management' and click on save
4. Go to your website in Website panel.
5. You will be able to see a Tab 'Web Publishing'and provide credentials.
6. Click on Enable and then on update

Now you should be able to use webdeploy with the credentials you provided in 'Web Publishing' tab.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

The video you have linked as you followed his tutorial, I left with first impression that he has made a video tutorial about a premium account so he has already paid for that hosting. MVC is a bit of a complicated method of making a website and hosting it online. You need a cloud server such as Google Cloud Platform or Azure. You can give it a go on AWS (Amazon Web Services) to host your ASP.NET products. GCP has 60 days of trial version + 300$ in cash that google is giving you for free to use their cloud system and spend these money during this period as you  wish whereas Azure is a cloud system provided by Microsoft and their 30 days trial is quietly far not enough but if you like it and find it for easy way of hosting your project, you can double check the pricing. AWS has a free option to host your ASP.NET MVC website.

Here it comes for the missing button you've mentioned. It seems like that you missed the payments and the button is inactive. You are not authorized to have access to this part of online publicity.

Kind regards,
Zen